# Homology group of $X=\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

My friend asks me how to compute the homology group of $X=\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$. It is not hard to see that $H_0(X)=\mathbb{Z}$, and for $q\ge 4$ we have $H_q(X)=0$.

But I don't know how to compute $H_q(X)$ for $q=1,2,3$, since the action of $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ seems 'strange' to me, and I can't make $X$ into a CW complex. Can anyone help me?

Comment: For $q \geq 4$ we have $H_q(X) = 0$ because $X$ is a 3-manifold.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks, my mistake.

Comment: It's a well-known fact that $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ is not cocompact in $SL(2,\mathbb R)$, so the quotient space is a non-compact manifold. It's also connected, so that $H_3(X)=0$. Now you just have to figure out $H_1$ and $H_2$. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The space of [unimodular lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_lattice) in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is acted upon transitively by $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, using the underlying action of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.  One can view such a matrix as containing a basis for a unimodular lattice.  The stabilizer of the $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ lattice is $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$, and so $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is in bijective correspondence with the space of unimodular lattices.

*(Warning: what follows is my attempt to expand out a story someone once told me. I don't know the theory of elliptic functions well enough to know I haven't made any mistakes.)*

The [Weierstrass elliptic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions) $\wp(z;\Lambda)$ for a complex number $z$ and a lattice $\Lambda$ for $\mathbb{C}$ gives a point on the Riemann sphere $\mathbb{C}_\infty$.  The quotient of $\mathbb{C}$ by a lattice is a flat torus, and $\wp(-;\Lambda)$ can be thought of as a function from a particular flat torus to the Riemann sphere with four branch points of order two, via a [hyperelliptic involution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14024/degree-2-branched-map-from-the-torus-to-the-sphere).  The four branch points are the images of $0,\omega_1/2,\omega_2/2,(\omega_1+\omega_2)/2$, where $\omega_1,\omega_2\in\mathbb{C}$ generate $\Lambda$.  Let
\begin{align*}
e_1&=\wp(\omega_1/2;\Lambda)\\
e_2&=\wp(\omega_2/2;\Lambda)\\
e_3&=\wp((\omega_1+\omega_2)/2;\Lambda)
\end{align*}
which are distinct elements of $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $e_1+e_2+e_3=0$.  These three numbers determine $\Lambda$ in that $\wp$ is the unique solution to the differential equation $(\frac{dy}{dz})^2=4(y-e_1)(y-e_2)(y-e_3)$ with a pole at $0$.  Expanded, the right-hand-side polynomial is $4y^3-g_2y-g_3$.  Hence, polynomials of this form parameterize lattices, if we exclude those that have double roots.  The discriminant of this polynomial is $(g_2^3-27 g_3^2)/16$, and $g_2^3-27 g_3^2$ is called the *modular discriminant*.

Every lattice has a unimodular representative by scaling, and in particular there is a deformation retract onto unimodular lattices.  So, if we take all lattices parameterized using $(g_2,g_3)$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$, remove those for which the discriminant is zero, then intersect with the unit $3$-sphere $\{(z,w):\lvert z\rvert^2+\lvert w\rvert ^2=1\}$, we have a parameterization of unimodular lattices after isotopy through the deformation retract.  It is known that the link of the singularity of $g_2^3-27 g_3^2$ (i.e., the intersection between the zero-set and $S^3$) is a trefoil knot. (There should be a way to say the condition on $g_2$ and $g_3$ so that the corresponding lattice is unimodular, but I couldn't find it.)

So: $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is homeomorphic to $S^3$ minus a trefoil knot, which can concretely be written as
$$\{(z,w)\in\mathbb{C}^2:\lvert z\rvert^2+\lvert w\rvert ^2=1\text{ and }z^3\neq 27w^3\}.$$
Knot complements have trivial reduced homology except $\tilde{H}_1(S^3-K)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ due to Alexander duality.

Stepping back a bit: if all we wanted was the fundamental group, then consider the following.  Recall that each lattice is parameterized by three distinct points in $\mathbb{C}$ which sum to $0$.  Unimodularity can be achieved after some positive real scaling factor of these points.  Loops in $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})/\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ correspond to loops in the configuration space of triples of distinct points.  Except for the small complication of rescaling which doesn't change anything homotopically, this is Artin's definition of the [braid group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_theory#Braids_and_configuration_spaces).

Comment: Very nice - this makes the picture eminently clear.

Comment: I know this is years later, but: I have a small question about this great answer. It's said that we can scale every lattice to a unimodular one, and then we take the lattice parameterization by $(g_2, g_3)$ and intersect with $S^3$. Is there a nice relationship between the discriminant of the lattice, and $|g_2|^2+|g_3|^2$?

Comment: @SteveD I think this is what the parenthetical statement at the end of that paragraph is about. I remember spending a couple hours trying to work that out, but nothing came of it.

Comment: @SteveD I remembered that it was actually [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4066425/the-3-component-hopf-link-covering-the-trefoil/4074976#4074976) where I tried to work something out, and I wrote some partial results near the end.

Comment: Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 7):

We may write just as well $X = \widetilde{SL_2 \Bbb R}/\widetilde{SL_2 \Bbb Z}$, where the latter term is the preimage of $SL_2 \Bbb Z$ under the covering map $\widetilde{SL_2 \Bbb R} \to SL_2 \Bbb R$. This identifes $X = B(\widetilde{SL_2 \Bbb Z}, 1)$, because its universal cover is the contractible space $\widetilde{SL_2 \Bbb R}$.

You are thus asking for a group homology computation. This is especially fortuitous because as a particularly emotive parsnip observed, $H_k X = 0$ for $k \geq 3$. So all we need to know is $H_k X = H_k(\widetilde{SL_2 \Bbb Z}; \Bbb Z)$ for $k = 1, 2$, where this last term means group homology (or equivalently, the homology of any space with contractible universal cover and $\pi_1 X = \widetilde{SL_2 \Bbb Z}$).

To facilitate things, observe that as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2125490/98602) this is the fundamental group of the complement of the trefoil knot, with presentation $\langle x, y \mid x^2 = y^3 \rangle.$  Knot complements always have aspherical universal cover, so we have $X \simeq S^3 \setminus T_{2,3}$, where $T_{2,3}$ is the trefoil knot. Knot complements always have $H_1 X = \Bbb Z$ and $H_k X = 0$ for $k > 1$ by Alexander duality or a Mayer-Vietoris calculation.

Likely there is an explicit homeomorphism, which I do not know but the clever 3-dimensional geometers do.

Comment: (I asked one of those clever 3-dimensional geometers and tried writing it up.)